# Run shortcode contact form in a hook - wordpress code snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contacts, code-snippets

Ok this is my first ever attempt at PHP/code snippets so I apologies in advance if I'm way off the mark!

I have a Wordpress website with a Real Estate Plugin that allows a logged in user to contact an agent (Landlord if you will). I would like to extend the plugin to use my own contact form (I'm using the plugin contact form 7) so that we get the email rather than the agent (We would then contact the agent on the users behalf)

I found the contact agent hook below by searching through the plugin code

```
      /**
     * single_property_contact_agent
     */
    public function single_property_contact_agent()
    {
        $property_form_sections = ere_get_option('property_form_sections', array('title_des', 'location', 'type', 'price', 'features', 'details', 'media', 'floors', 'agent'));
        $hide_contact_information_if_not_login = ere_get_option('hide_contact_information_if_not_login', 0);
        if ($hide_contact_information_if_not_login == 0) {
            if (in_array('contact', $property_form_sections)) {
                ere_get_template('single-property/contact-agent.php');
            }
        } else {
            if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                if (in_array('contact', $property_form_sections)) {
                    ere_get_template('single-property/contact-agent.php');
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <p class="ere-account-sign-in"><?php esc_attr_e('Please login or register to view contact information for this agent/owner', 'essential-real-estate'); ?>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#ere_signin_modal">
                        <?php esc_html_e('Login', 'essential-real-estate'); ?>
                    </button>
                </p>
                <?php
            }
        }

    }
```

My idea is to use code snippet below to hook onto the above and load our form instead (using the contact form shortcode)

```
add_action('single_property_contact_agent', 'reg_form_before_content');

function reg_form_before_content() {

echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="524" title="Register Interest"]');

   }
```

Currently nothing happens so I maybe way off the mark of what is possible here but if anyone can help I would be forever grateful

Many thanks!

Comment: actions added via `add_action` are triggered via a `do_action` somewhere.  A good developer will include `do_action` and `apply_filters` in places in their code to allow others to extend their functionality.  Unfortunately there is no corresponding `do_action` in the code, so your code never runs.  **However** you may be in luck: that developer is using a template (`single-property/contact-agent.php`, and based on how the code is written above, I'd guess they provide some sort of template override system.  Check out their docs and explore using your own custom contact template.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the mark, conceptually speaking. I think this is more or less The WordPress Way™: hooking into actions and filters in order to modify output/behaviour. So bravo to you there.

The trouble is, that *function* you're targeting doesn't implement any calls to `apply_filter('filter_name', $data)`, or `do_action('hook_name', $var)`.

There's a tricky norm in a lot of WordPress code where the name of a function is also the name of a filter or action. But that is a coincidence.

---

All this being said, you might look at the source of the `ere_get_template` function. Maybe it's employing a sort of [template inheritance like WooCommerce 
does](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

That is to say - if you create a template relative to your theme folder called `single-property/contact-agent.php`, it may check for a template you've provided, before defaulting to it's own.

Comment: Nice answer.  I was attempting to stuff all that sort of info into a comment :)

Comment: Cheers, Cale. Talk about synchronicity, eh?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, this has really helped so thank you :). I have found the property/contact-agent.php folder in the back end FTP and within that I can see the Filter and Do actions. I have not had time to investigate further but creating a relative template does make sense so I feel one step closer to my goal. I will obviously come back once I have further info.